# How can you add clickable text in a SwiftUI Text() View?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-text, swiftui-button

I've seen people using AttributedString and .link to link to something, but I need it to run a function, not open a browser link. I want something like this in SwiftUI, with wrapping, etc.
[Terms of service agreement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2P1r.png)
(this image was made with HTML)

I tried buttons, but that results in

```
HStack {
   Text("By clicking continue you agree to our ")
   Button("Terms Of Service") {}
   Text(" and our ")
   Button("Privacy Policy") {}
}
```

Awful Looking TOS notification:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use Text

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var text: String = ""
@State var textTapped: String = ""
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack(spacing: 0){
            Text("Just text ")
            Text("tap me").onTapGesture {
                tapped()
            }
            Text(" some more text")
        }
        Text(textTapped)
    }
}

func tapped() {
    textTapped = "was tapped"
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: That still doesn't let them wrap with the text, so you still get my screenshot above when you do that. It's just using the Text() view instead of Button()

Comment: So, we have a text, it's tappable and runs a method. Looks like I don't understand, what you really want to achieve.